# how to display many to many field properly in django

Tags: django

This code saves the data and displays the data as i wanted.but while displaying courses it displays like this **, ]>** .It displays with 
QuerySet[].i only want the courses name to be displayed.How can i do that

> models.py

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Teachers',blank=True)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
```

> views.py

```
def viewteacher(request):
        teachers = Teacher.objects.all().order_by('-joined_date')
        year1 = datetime.datetime.today().year

        return render(request,'students/view_teacher.html',{'teachers':teachers,'year_list':range(2016,year1+1)})
```

> template

```
  {% for teacher in teachers %}
                <tr> 
                    <td>{{teacher.name}}</div></td>
                        <td>{{teacher.courses.all}}</td>
                        <td>{{teacher.address}}</td>
                        <td>{{teacher.phone}}</td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'students:profile_teacher' teacher.id %}">Profile</a></td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'students:edit_teacher' teacher.id %}">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'students:confirm_delete_teacher' teacher.id %}">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                   {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `QuerySet` is rendered like `<QuerySet [ ... ]>`, so you can iterate over the queryset, and render it properly, like:

```
{% for teacher in teachers %}
<tr> 
    <td>{{teacher.name}}</div></td>
    <td>{% for course in teacher.courses %} {{course.name}} {% endfor %}</td>
    <td>{{teacher.address}}</td>
    <td>{{teacher.phone}}</td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'students:profile_teacher' teacher.id %}">Profile</a></td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'students:edit_teacher' teacher.id %}">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'students:confirm_delete_teacher' teacher.id %}">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Obtain the list of courses for every individual teacher is however not very efficient. You can use `.prefetch_related` to speed up the process. It will then perform a limited number of queries to fetch all the courses, and link these properly to the correct teacher(s):

```
def viewteacher(request):
    teachers = Teacher.objects.prefetch_related('courses').order_by('-joined_date')
    year1 = datetime.datetime.today().year

    return render(
        request,
        'students/view_teacher.html',
        {'teachers':teachers,'year_list':range(2016,year1+1)}
    )
```